# Qt linker errors windows

Tags: c++, qt, linker

I'm trying to run this code, but all I get is linker errors and don't really know what to do or what I'm doing wrong here. Been struggling way too long with this now, any help is greatly appreciated so I can get this thing going. This is  also my first Qt-application ever.

Running Qt Creator 3.5.1, Based on Qt 5.5.1 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)
Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0
OS: Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit

I have Qt project where I have files:

**Hasher.h**

```
#ifndef HASHER_H
#define HASHER_H

#include <QString>
#include <QCryptographicHash>

class Hasher : public QCryptographicHash
{
public:
    Hasher(const QByteArray &data, Algorithm method); /* Constructor */
    ~Hasher(); /* Destructor */

    QString name, output;
private:
    QCryptographicHash *QCryptObject;
};

#endif // HASHER_H
```

**Hasher.cpp**

```
#include "hasher.h"

/* Destructor */
Hasher::~Hasher() {

}

/*
 * Constructor Hasher(QByteArray &, Algorithm) generates hash
 * from given input with given algorithm-method
*/
Hasher::Hasher(const QByteArray &data, Algorithm method) {
   QByteArray result = this->QCryptObject->hash(data, method);
   this->output = result.toHex();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

#include "hasher.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString fileName;
    QTextStream stream(stdin);

    qDebug() << "MD5 generator!" << endl;
    qDebug() << "Give filename to generate checksum from: ";
    fileName = stream.readLine();
    QFile* file = new QFile(fileName);
        if(file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
            {
                Hasher hasher(file->readAll(), QCryptographicHash::Md5);
                qDebug() << "MD5 Hash of " << fileName << " is: " << hasher.output << endl;
                file->close();
            }
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Errors I get:**

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Hasher::Hasher(class QByteArray const &,enum QCryptographicHash::Algorithm)" (??0Hasher@@QEAA@AEBVQByteArray@@W4Algorithm@QCryptographicHash@@@Z) referenced in function main

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Hasher::~Hasher(void)" (??1Hasher@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main

debug\MD5-generator.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

**.pro file**

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = MD5-generator
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    hasher.cpp

HEADERS += \
    hasher.h
```

Comment: Remove `Hasher::` from your header function definitions to start.

Comment: @William_Wilson, while this is an error, it will not cause linker issues.

Comment: @William_Wilson Did that, no help.

Comment: Not familiar with windows linker. Are you sure it sees all the .o files when it links?

Comment: Where you create `QCryptographicHash *QCryptObject`?

Comment: @SergeyA No I'm not, and I'm afraid I don't know how to find it out. Gotta check this.

Comment: @Mpak91 The above code cannot be compiled. So, it is strange that you have linker error. Probably the makefiles and object files are not updated. You can try: Clean, Run qmake, and Build. You should see compiler errors.

Comment: Anyway, you should decide whether to subclass from `QCryptographicHash` or to use it as private member. If it is private member it shound be istantiated  first. If you subclass it you do not need `QCryptographicHash *QCryptObject;`

Comment: @Orest Hera I made changes suggested in Paul's post then did Clean, Run qmake and Build all and it works! Thank you for your reply. So I guess problem was makefiles and object-files were not updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the linker error resulted from not updated makefiles and object files, since the new `Hasher.cpp` was not compled at all. In that case rebuilding project may help: `Clean`, `Run qmake`, `Build`.

Answer (score 2):

In `Hasher::Hasher` you need to call base class constructor:

```
Hasher::Hasher(const QByteArray &data, Algorithm method)
    : QCryptographicHash(method)
{
   QByteArray result = this->hash(data, method);
   this->output = result.toHex();
}
```

I have no idea why MSVC compiles that code at all, it should not even get to linking.

Comment: Of course it fixes compilation error, but it does not explain the linker error.

Comment: @OrestHera I have no access to MSVC at the moment, but I won't be surprised if it compiles that code as it was quoted.

Comment: Tried this, still same errors. Thanks for the suggestion though.